# GAE why am i billed less instances than im using?

Tags: google-app-engine

I have a limit of 1 instance min and max in the settings.

But why is GAE using more than one instance and its not billing it to me?

[image: instances]

Comment: You will need to ask Google. Stack Overflow is not a customer support site.

Comment: in fact it is https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-appengine/Z6XN_64cA7w thanks for your constructive participation

Comment: maybe others might have the same question and its helpful to the community?

Comment: I have to agree with Felix. Billing and development on appengine are very connected. This IS a development question.

Comment: This question _is_ better suited to the groups, since it's not of a technical nature.

Comment: why dont you guys just IGNORE this question if you dont like it and use your valuable time to HELP someone else, instead of WASTING ENERGY to find out if its worth to be closed...

Answer (score 2):

you did most probably set max idle instances to 1.
the scheduler is still spinning up more instances to handle request spikes but the billed instances do not go over you setting.

Comment: yes i set max to 1 idle instance, so google is just beeing nice to give me some more free instances? i like it :)

Answer (score 1):

You're not charged for instances that have been idle for more than 15 minutes. The App Engine infrastructure may leave unused instances running if it has no reason to shut them down.